# One tick lower than B flat minor on 48 Bass accordion

Tags: chords, scales, accordion

I like the B flat minor chord on my 48 Bass accordion.
I play F minor to go up one "tick" (don't know the proper word), but what could I play to go down a tick? There's no A flat minor.

Comment: If one tick up from Bbmi is Fmi, shouldn't one tick down from Bbmi be Ebmi, not Abmi?

Comment: @Divizna how did you determine that?

Comment: I kind of assumed that the shift by a "tick" should be a consistent interval. From Bb to F, it's a fifth up. A fifth down from Bb is Eb.

Comment: @Divizna How would I determine what the fifth down of any note is myself?

Comment: You need to know the tones and how they come after one another, and the intervals. It's something like the very first thing in musical theory to learn (well, possibly after some basics of rhythm). From there it becomes obvious.

Comment: @Divizna Yeah, might be time.

Comment: If you wanted to go one "tick" down from F minor, where would you go? And/or what’s one "tick" down for any other chord where you know what one tick down is?

Comment: Looking at this page indeed it seems you cannot play Abm (or rather G#m) on a 48 bass accordion: https://accordionchords.com/stradella-bass-layouts/48-bass-accordion-chart-8x6/ But there is a button adjacent to Bbm, and that's Ebm.

Comment: I think we need some clarification. If "tick" means "I use the button immediately above the Bb minor, the F button," then you could also simply use the button below, the Eb m.